# Allocate memory for a pointer in a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, constructor, operator-overloading

I am working on a program but can't understand working with pointers when classes are involved. I know I have to allocate memory for the pointer using `new` and am fine with this when not using classes. I can't find a simple tutorial to explain how to do this particular task though. Could someone please give me some help? This is the relevant snippets what I have done so far but it is outputting random characters:

```
"Hangman.c"
{

class Hangman
{
public:
...
char* remainingLetters();
Hangman()
 {
  char* remaining=new char[26];
 }
~Hangman();

private:
char* remaining;
}

"Hangman.cpp"
{

...
 char* Hangman::remainingLetters()
{
 ...does task to find remaining letters;

 return remaining;
 }

  ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Hangman &game)
  {
    out << "Letters remaining are: " << game.remaining <<endl

    return out;
  }
}

"main.cpp"
{
...
cout << game;
...
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't really be using pointers or `new` at all in C++, **especially** if you're a beginner. They're niche expert topics for library developers.

Comment: Going with the theme of not using pointers, why not just declare the member variable as an array? I.e. `char remaining[26];` Then you don't have to worry about things like memory leaks, like if you forget to free the memory in the destructor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I need to return an array each time the function is called, which can't be done in C++ if I remember correctly. That's why I am trying to use a pointer. Would it be possible to get an array output in this case?

Comment: An array can be converted to a pointer of the same type, i.e. you can do something like `char array[26]; char *pointer = array; printf("pointer[1] = '%c'\n", pointer[1]);`

Comment: @adohertyd - You **can** use a `std::string` to store your letters. There are no problems returning C++ strings, just arrays.

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem: Why your first file's extension is `.c` and the second one `.cpp`?! First one should be `.h`.

Comment: In this case (remaining characters), I would suggest std::set: his biggest concern is probably removing used characters and checking whether a character is still remaining.

Comment: A warning: if you want to print out the remaining characters as a null-terminated string (cout << game.remaining;) you need to reserve space for a null (char[26+1]) and make sure your remaining letters are always terminated by the null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initializing you member. You should have:

```
Hangman()
{
   remaining=new char[26];
}
```

Your version:

```
 Hangman()
 {
    char* remaining=new char[26];
 }
```

initializes a local variable called `remaining`, whose scope is the constructor.

**Also** you should `delete[]` the memory in the destructor and implement the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: *"Implement the copy constructor **OR** assignment operator"*  No!, it should be *"Implement the copy constructor **AND** assignment operator"*

Comment: This is the correct answer. Still don't have the code working though. Have to do a lot more reading on this topic. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 3):

Most of the problems go away if you use a C++ string instead of a C style array of char.

```
class Hangman 
{ 
public:
    std::string remainingLetters(); 

    Hangman()  { } 

private:
    std::string   remaining; 
};
```

"Hangman.cpp"

```
std::string Hangman::remainingLetters() 
{
    //  ...does task to find remaining letters;
   return remaining;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Hangman()
{
  char* remaining=new char[26];
}
```

In the constructor, you are initializing a local variable but not the class member. Also, every `new/new[]` should be associated with `delete/delete[]` respectively to avoid memory leaks. In stead of managing memory yourself, use **smart pointers** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Few important points:

- You need to allocate memory using `new []` to the pointer member in the constructor.
- You need to deallocate the memory using `delete []` in the destructor.
- You need to follow the **Rule of Three**.

Also, note that creating a local pointer in the constructor with same name as your class member `remaining` is at best ambigiuos and you should rename it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

One side aspect is that by doing

```
remaining=new char[26];
```

you are reserving space for 25 letters (+ one 0-byte), which is probably not what you want...

Regards

Andreas